# How to map to an entity which is not directly related

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I am using spring-data-jdbc and I have following tables -

`table course_details {course_id, course_name}`

Example - {1, 'Primary Education'}, {2, 'Secondary Education'}

`table course_year {year_id, year_name, course_id}`

Example - {1, 'Year 1', 1}, {2, 'Year 11', 2}

`table subject {subject_id, subject_name}`

Example - {1, 'Mathematics'}, {2, 'Political Science'}

`table topic {topic_id, topic_name, related_subject_id, related_year_id}`

Example - {1, 'Adding 2 numbers', 1, 1}, {2, 'South Asian Politics', 2, 2}

Entity classes, corresponding to these tables are -

```
class CourseDetail {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<CourseYear> years;
}
```

```
class CourseYear {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Subjects> subjects; --> No relation to subject, still need this
}
```

```
class Subject {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Topics> topics;
}
```

and

```
class Topic {
    int id;
    String name;
    int relatedSubjectId;
}
```

Now question here is -

How to map subjects thing in CourseYear class, so that I can get a courseGroupById(say 2) and I then get this info -

```
Course id = 2 (CourseDetail.getId())
Course name = Secondary Education (CourseDetail.getname())
Year = 11 year (CourseDetail.getYears().get(0).getName())
Subject name = Political Science (CourseDetail.getYears().get(0).getSubjects().get(0).getName())
Topic name = South Asian Politics (CourseDetail.getYears().get(0).getSubjects().get(0).getTopics().get(0).getName())
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `course_group.course_id` is supposed to be a PK and therefore the sample data contains a typo? Or should it be `group_id` instead? Is `CourseDetail` supposed to be mapped to `course_group`?

Comment: you're right. corrected the table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to map something like this in Spring Data JDBC.
A very fundamental idea of Spring Data JDBC is to map aggregates to trees of relational tables.
Your scenario does not describe this situation at all.

You should not have `subjects` as an attribute in `CourseYear`. Instead you should have a method in the `SubjectRepository` giving you all the `Subject` instances for a given `CourseYear`

If your model is intended to be read only you could alternatively create a view in the database to map `CourseYear` to which contains the `Subject` information.

Another alternative is to make the attribute transient and load it in an `AfterConvertCallback` or `AfterConvertEvent`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Are you suggesting that there is no way to map subject with year? And only way to get this done is - either view or a join query at repository level?

Comment: I tried to improve and clarify the answer.